# Add to array only once - leaving unique items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I program a function that give me all values of some input checkboxes and include them into an array.

Function:

```
$('#area_tbl .checkbox').each(function(){
    /*for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
        if(test[i].PLZ === $(this).find('.area-checkbox').val()){
            alert('Gleich');
        }else{
            alert('nicht gleich');
        }
    }*/
    test.push({PLZ:$(this).find('.area-checkbox').val()});
});
```

My array looks like this:

```
[Object { PLZ="42799"}]
```

That's fine!

Now I include automatically more checkboxes with more values. After that my function is refreshing and I include the 'new' values.

Now my problem is that my array looks like this:

```
 [Object { PLZ="42799"}, Object { PLZ="42799"}, Object { PLZ="51399"}]
```

You can see `PLZ='42799'` is twice.

I want to find the duplicate values and delete them from my array. I try it with the if clause in my function. But nothing works for me.

Comment: does each checkbox `.area-checkbox` has unique value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that value of each checkbox is unique, you need to reset the `test` value before running this `each` iterator

```
  test = [];
  $('#area_tbl .checkbox').each(function(){
        test.push({PLZ:$(this).find('.area-checkbox').val()});
   });
```

Comment: 4 hours.. and I don't get this solutions... weekend is coming. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a memory

```
    // The memory will be a simple list with the already added elements. Firstly empty
    memory = []

    // we loop over ther checboxes
    $('#area_tbl .checkbox').each(function(){

        // we store the value
        var v = $(this).find('.area-checkbox').val();

        // If memory doesn't content the value... (its position is -1)
        if(memory.indexOf(v) == -1){

            // we store the object and we update the memory
            test.push({PLZ:v});
            memory.push(v);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporary object and look up with accessing the property:

```
var object= {};

$('#area_tbl .checkbox').each(function() {
    var v = $(this).find('.area-checkbox').val();
    if (!object[v]) {
        test.push({PLZ: v});
        object[v] = true;
    }
});
```